# How to make vert.x project work in a Docker container?

Tags: java, maven, docker, vert.x

I downloaded a vert.x starter project from http://start.vertx.io/ and would like to run the compiled binary with `java -jar ..` inside a Docker container.

Current invocation command:

```
mvn package exec:java -DskipTests
```

Current `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM java:10
COPY target/project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar project.jar
ENTRYPOINT java -jar project.jar
```

which gives the following error message when run

> no main manifest attribute, in
>   /project/target/vertx-start-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Is there a simpler way than building a full deployment assembly as is usually done with Maven?

Answer (score 2):

When you run a command like so:

```
mvn package exec:java
```

The vert.x specfic configuration will make Maven create:

```
SNAPSHOT.jar
SNAPSHOT-fat.jar
```

like so:

[image]

the fat.jar has all the files in it, so you only need to copy that jar file to the Docker image.

```
FROM openjdk:10-jre-slim
COPY target/SNAPSHOT-fat.jar fat.jar
ENTRYPOINT java -jar fat.jar
```

you build the docker image with:

```
docker build -t foo .
```

then run the docker image as a container with:

```
docker run -it foo
```

Answer (score 0):

A runnable jar requires a `Main-Class` entry in MANIFEST.MF with the name of the class to launch.

You will most likely also need your dependencies copied in.

Consider this a full  deployment of your application.

Comment: All that needs to be done is to use the fat.jar file and copy that to the Docker image, please see my answer.

Comment: Please don’t spam all other answers with a reference t your own answer. Let the voting mechanism work instead.

Comment: i honestly had to hold myself back from criticizing the other answers as poor and downvoting them.

Comment: Ah, you answered your own question - sorry, but didn't expect that an 18k user would ask such a poorly worded question.  Therefore I suggest that you edit both to clearly indicate that this question is about vert.x because your answer is not valid generally but only for vert.x projects.

Comment: Now that you understand the question, can you add an answer that is more general and not only for vertx projects? I will accept it if so, ty

Comment: @AlexanderMills No.  That would just be a duplicate and closed as such.  Just finish what you started.

Comment: i dont know the answer besides using a fat.jar file, i dont use java or vertx much

Comment: I edited your question so it is  hopefully not just a poor and downvotable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/574594/53897 but now a vert.x specific question to fit your own answer.

Comment: do you think anything else is necessary in the Dockerfile or is that one jar enough

Answer (score 0):

Like what Thorbjørn said, this command executes a "runnable" jar, which means it should have packed with a MANIFEST.MF that points to some certian main method in your project

Comment: All that needs to be done is to use the fat.jar file and copy that to the Docker image, please see my answer.